# Unable to get SQL Server connections from a connection pool in ado.net

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

We are having problems with Ado.net running inside an Azure web app where when we try to open a connection and sometimes it never gets past the connection.open statement. We are running the connection open inside a task which has a timeout of over twice the connection timeout.

The task timeout is 31s and the connection timeout is 15s. What is happening is that the task times out and we never get a connection. However, if we look at the process dump the connection pool only has its minimum number of connections (50), which itself is more than enough for the application. Once this starts to happen we typically get a burst of failures for a few minutes before it eventually sorts itself out.

This is a cut down version of the code:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => OpenAndRun(cmd, trackingId));
if (task.Wait(31000, token)) return task.Result;

private static SqlDataReader OpenAndRun(SqlCommand sqlCommand)
{
    sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 15;
    sqlCommand.Connection.Open();  
    return sqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
}
```

This is the connection string:

```
<add name="conn" 
     connectionString="data source=ddd;initial catalog=ccc;user id=uuu;password=ppp;Min Pool Size=50;Max Pool Size=500;TimeOut=180;application name=aaaaa" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Our database has plenty of capacity for extra connections.

Things we have tried:

1. Increasing the min pool size. This seems to make little difference.
2. Decreasing the min pool size. Looking at the process dumps we can see our application happily will rise from the min pool size when it needs to.

Comment: This is because you are not disposing of your connections and your connection pool will be decimated. Why do you have a separate method to open a command and execute it? You should get rid of that method and add a USING statement around your command and connection objects.

Comment: The connections ARE being closed. The CommandBehavior.CloseConnection replicates the using statement. It's not possible to use a using statement because the SqlDataReader which the command produces is being returned to the calling function.

Comment: Right but the connection is not being disposed. Closed and disposed are two different things. This means that the connection is not returned to the pool.

Comment: Passing commands and data readers around is not a good practice because you need to be able to manage your connections more cleanly.

Comment: `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` all implement the `IDisposable` interface.  

You should re-think your design so that no function ever returns a `DataReader`, especially since you can only use the `DataReader` with an open connection.  
Either use data tables or [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)s instead.